# Make a nested reference in one Model class Table

Tags: django

I'd like to make a table with such a structure

```
1. urls
2. views
3. models
4. templates
4.1 html
4.2 format
4.3 test
```

html, format and test live in the same level with others but reference to 4. templates

I could start from the simple easy model as:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    """A topic the user is learning about."""
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    sub_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

How to reference 'sub_title' to 'title'

Comment: Can the nesting be arbitrary deep (like `4.1.2.7.1`) or only at most two levels?

Comment: Arbitrary deep is best, two levels are good for me now. @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a *tree-like* structure. A tree is basically a set of nodes (here topics) where a node can have at most one parent. There are no cycles in the parent relation (hence a node's grandparent can not be itself for example).

One can define such tree-like structure, by adding a reference to the parent, and that reference can be `None` (for top level nodes). So we can model this with:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    """A topic the user is learning about."""
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'Topic',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        default=None,
    )
```

Since your topics have an index number as well, this means that we can add an `IntegerField` with the index, and prefereably, the `index` and `parent` need to be unique together, such that we can not define two `4.2`s:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    """A topic the user is learning about."""
    index = models.IntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'Topic',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        default=None,
    )

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('parent', 'index'),)
        ordering = ('index',)
```

So now we model the hierarchy with:

```
Topic.objects.create(index=1, title='urls')
Topic.objects.create(index=2, title='views')
Topic.objects.create(index=3, title='models')
templates = Topic.objects.create(index=4, title='templates')
Topic.objects.create(index=1, title='html', parent=templates)
Topic.objects.create(index=2, title='format', parent=templates)
tests = Topic.objects.create(index=3, title='tests', parent=templates)
```

Now we can obtain the parent of a topic, by calling `.parent`:

```
tests.parent  # templates
```

We can also obtain an (ordered) set of subtopics with `.topic_set`:

```
templates.topic_set  # queryset with [html, format, tests]
```